# Download file and redirect to page or vice versa

Tags: php, redirect

I have a Wordpress site with a custom post type called `downloads`. The post type has a [file field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/) added to it with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). The `downloads` post type is used for download links spread across the site and I want them to sometimes be password protected using the native password protection of pages in Wordpress.

When clicking a link to a `downloads` post type, you're directed to `www.domain.com/?downloads=<NAME OF POST>&redirect=<CURRENT URL>`. If the download is password protected, you need to enter the correct password and then click "Enter".

What I then want is for the visitor to automatically download the file connected to the post and be redirected to the page where the download link was clicked initially. The order of this is not really important, as long as the file is being downloaded when entering the correct password and that you are redirected to the URL you was on before.

The redirect to the initial URL is set up by having the parameter called `redirect`, that stores the URL that the user was on when clicking on the download link.

The code I have so far is a very slight modification of the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954422/4880498) for how to initialize a download and then redirect the user to another page:

**single-downloads.php**

```
<?php function force_file_download($filepath, $filename = ''){
        if($filename == ''){
            $filename = basename($filepath);
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\""); 
        readfile($filepath); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)  
    }
?>

<?php
    if (!empty(get_query_var('redirect'))) {
        $redirect_url = get_query_var('redirect');
    } else {
        $redirect_url = get_bloginfo("url");
    }
?>

<?php 
//If download is password protected and correct password has not been entered yet, show password protection form
if (post_password_required()) {
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <main id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
    </main>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
} else { ?>
// If download is not password protected or correct password has been entered, do download
        $url = get_field("upload_file")['url'];
        force_file_download($url);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "' . $redirect_url . '"';
        echo '</script>';
<?php } ?>
```

Everything until the redirection is working with the code above. I can enter the correct password and the file is being downloaded, but the redirection is halted. I imagine this is because the header for the file download is conflicting with the redirect (made with JavaScript). The password form is still showing when the file is downloaded, so it seems like the loading of the template in Wordpress is being halted as well.

Is it even possible to make it so that the file is downloaded and the user is then redirected to the URL in the `redirect` URL parameter? And in that case, how do I do it? Like I mentioned, the exact order is not really important to me as long as the file is being downloaded while you are redirected to the initial URL.